# Can't divide by zero exception

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I know my error is a common one, but I do have an if condition to catch this error. I'm working with android studio. The language I'm using is kotlin.

I want to calculate this formula: A = ((2*varX)+varF) / (varX-(2*varF)).

There are two main problems, one is that X and F are 0, I have an if statement for this. The second issue would be if F is half of X, this would give me 0 in my denominator.

Since I'm working with android studio I have two input boxes where the user inputs the variables. I have already validated that the user inputs only numbers and that the camps are not left empty. I have no issue here. My problem is when I input 2 and 1. This would cause my denominator to be 0.
When this happens, I get an error and my app shuts down.

```
var auxiliar = varF/2
if (varX != 0 && varF != 0 && auxiliar != varX) {
    var resultado = ((2*varX)+varF) / (varX-(2*varF))
    resultadoFormula.setText("a = ${resultado}")
} else {
    message("Combinacion Incorrecta")
}
```

This is my code. I would appreciate the help.

I get this error.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.eval_2_data, PID: 8657
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure `varX != 2*varF`, because if it does the denominator is 0. `((2*varX)+varF) / (varX-(2*varF))` will have `2-2*1` in the denominator, which is 0 because of pemdas. Whenever there is division by 0, this will cause an exception to get thrown.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of doing this. but since I had an auxiliary variable I thought this would help, but looking at my conditions again, this was not solving the issue.

Comment: If you had made auxiliar = 2*varF instead of varF/2 it would have. Would you mind clicking the checkmark on my answer?

Comment: I would change `auxiliar` to `denominator` and put the whole denominator formula there, change the check to `denominator != 0`, and reuse `denominator` when dividing. This eliminates the repetition (and variation) of your calculation that resulted in your bug. All that you need to check is if the denominator would be 0. Trying to overthink it and say, well if the denominator were to be zero, it would mean  `varF` would be such-and-such, and then checking that is convoluted and error-prone.

Comment: Also, this reasoning can bite you because of integer division. For example. `val x = 5; val y = x / 2; println(x == y * 2)` will print false because `y` is 2, not `2.5`.

Answer (score -1):

A try catch block will stop the fatal error and allow the app to continue running.

```
var auxiliar = varF/2

try {
     if (varX != 0 && varF != 0 && auxiliar != varX) {
     var resultado = ((2*varX)+varF) / (varX-(2*varF))
     resultadoFormula.setText("a = ${resultado}")
} else {
     message("Combinacion Incorrecta")
     }
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
     System.out.println("I didn't do my math correctly.")
}
```

Comment: This is a bad habit to form, it is inefficient, and it could lead to a lot of problems if not the issue is not recognized.